# MySQL Use Array From Non Existent Column

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I'm not sure if my title is even worded correctly.  Hopefully I can explain this in a concise manner.  I'm trying to select all from a database:

```
if (! empty ( $fname ) && ! empty ( $lname )) {
        $query5 = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "customer_det where (fname = '" . $fname . "' and lname = '" . $lname . "')";
            $result5 = $mysqli->query ( $query5 ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    } else {
        $query5 = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "customer_det where phone = '" . $phone . "'";

        $result5 = $mysqli->query ( $query5 ) or die ( mysql_error () );

    }
```

Then my next statement basically says if $result5 === NULL then insert stuff.  Problem is I'm var_dump($result5) and it looks like it's printing out an array.

```
object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(34) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Basically what I'm trying to say is how can I write an IF $result5 = non existent statement.  Is it a count or num_rows function im looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli_result object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

You want to check one of it's properties not for `null`, for example:

```
if ($result5->num_rows == 0)
```

**Note:** I also encourage you to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Thanks Jason I'll go ahead and try that.  This is the first time using the improved MySQLi module after three weeks using PHP 4.8 without MySQLi, etc

Comment: No worries. If you are new `mysqli`, you may want to jump straight to PDO. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Jason, I read your comments on that blog.  Why do you advocate PDO over MySQLi?  I've seen a little documentation on both and I have an entire volume of OReilly and Apress books on both but I'm curious if there's more benefits with PDO.  I did read that the PDO connector does work with a number of databases. I have read all about SQL injection and sanitizing input.  I have some form validation regarding the input boxes.  I've seen the real escape functions, etc.  Fortunately or unfortunately, what I'm coding is in a protected area. A user account would have to be compromised first.

Comment: Why don't you move your comment to that post and we'll continue our discussion there.